# Restriction of an injective function

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, solution-verification

> Prove that if f : A → B is an injective function and C ⊆ A, then f[C] : C → B is an injective function.

I am trying proof the following, I need that someone tell me if I did it right. Could you give me some suggestions to make the proofs right.

[image]

Comment: Since $C\subseteq A$, if you take any elements in $C$, they will also be elements of $A$, so anything that applies to every choice of elements in $A$ will in particular apply to those of $C$.

Comment: @Javi so my proof is correct?

Comment: No, you have to show that if $x_1,x_2\in C$ are such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: As and advice, you should write your attemp on the question instead of posting a picture. And what's more, you should write it in english since most users can't read spanish.

Comment: @Javi the question is in english.  Prove that if f : A → B is an injective function and C ⊆ A, then f[C] : C → B is an injective function.

Comment: I know, but your attempt is not.